# Operator[] overloading returns wrong data

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've followed the operator overloading tutorial from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/subscripting_operator_overloading.htm).

This is my class:

```
struct Decimal {

private:
    int16_t  exponent;
    uint8_t  length;
    uint16_t mantissa[DecimalMaxSize]{};
...
public:
    uint16_t &operator[](int i);
...
```

and my implementation:

```
uint16_t &Decimal::operator[](int i) {
    if( i > DecimalMaxSize ) {
        std::cout << "Index out of bounds" << std::endl;
        // return first element.
        return mantissa[0];
    }
    return mantissa[i];
}
```

When I now want to use this like this:

```
Decimal *d = new Decimal(...);
uint16_t di = d[i];
```

I receive the following error: "No viable conversion from 'Decimal' to 'uint16_t'"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why the `new`? Do not use it. Try `Decimal d (...);`

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#. You don’t need `new` and a pointer here.

Comment: @Amadeus Don't try to fix a problem that is none...

Comment: @molbdnilo Don't try to fix a problem that is none...

Comment: @ChristianSeiler if there is no problem, why are you posting a question? Remove the `new` operator and the code will problably run. Then, you will have a good point to think what you are doing wrong

Comment: On a side note, `if( i > DecimalMaxSize )` should be `if( i >= DecimalMaxSize )`. And does it really make sense to return `mantissa[0]` for an invalid index? Why not throw an exception instead, like `std::out_of_range`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d[i];` will be an operation to index array of `Decimal` objects because `d` is a pointer. In order to call overloaded `operator []` on object itlsef you should dereference this pointer first and write `(*d)[i]` or `d->operator [](i);`

Comment: or `d[0][i]` which will access the pointed to object then call the `[]` operator.

Comment: @doug Some would consider such usage incorrect because pointer `d` does not point to an array of objects though.

Comment: Isn't it the same as an array with one element? To me `(*d)` and `d`[0]`look the same but I agree the former notation is more usually seen as referring to an isolated object so perhaps conveys more context. Pretty rare to see this though. Usually such objects are instantiated in place, not on the heap.

Comment: @doug Yeah, it would be the same, but some coding practices and tools require you to keep track of array size when indexing a pointer like this and writing array size of 1 out of thin air won't be conformant.

Comment: Agree. it's legal but not good practice, like much of C++ code.